# Showing a null value instead of token value

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating this code where I am supposed to prompt the user for a maximum of 5 integer numbers. I should store the 5 integers in an array by asking the user to enter them until the array is full or the user exits by entering -99. Then I should print out all the values of the array and calculate the average. The problem is that when I scan and store the values it shows me a null value of 0 of the fifth number instead of the number itself and it does not count it with the sum. This is the piece of code I've been working with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean cond = false;
    int i = 0;
    int[] number = new int[5];
    double sum = 0;
    do{
        int num = scan.nextInt();


        if(num==-99 || i==4){
            for(int k=0; k<i+1; k++){
                System.out.println(number[k]);
                sum = sum + number[k];
            }
            System.out.println(sum/i);
            cond = true;
        }


        number[i] = num;


        i++;





    }while(!cond);

}
```

This is the input : 1 2 3 4 5 
Every number is on a separate line
This is the output:

```
run:
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
0
2.5
```

Comment: This is a problem you should debug yourself.  This one is simple enough that you can trace through it with a pencil and paper--figure out what the program is doing at each statement, and I think you should easily able to figure out what's wrong.  Another possibility is `System.out.println` at some key places to see how the program is operating.  Print out some values at the beginning of the `for (int k` loop and when you say `number[i] = num`.

Comment: I'd like to request that _nobody_ give the answer to this question.  The OP will learn more by trying to debug it themselves.

Comment: @DamianLattenero I can't put things on hold by myself unless it's a duplicate.  Even if I could, I don't think it would be a good enough reason to put something on hold.

Comment: M.J, user ajb has a point, I was about to answer, but I think the best here is to follow the trace of you code, add some extra `System.out.println`, and believe you will feel really good when you figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
number[i] = num;
```

is what adds the number the user entered to the array. If they enter -99, it's in the correct place. If they've simply entered all 4 however, it is in the wrong place. Also, you have it so it is actually dividing by the wrong number. Something like this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean cond = false;
    int i = 0;
    int[] number = new int[5];
    double sum = 0;
    do{
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        if(num!=-99){
           number[i] = num;
           i++;
        }

        if(num==-99 || i==5){
            for(int k=0; k<i; k++){
                System.out.println(number[k]);
                sum = sum + number[k];
            }
            System.out.println(sum/(i));
            cond = true;
        }

    }while(!cond);
}
```

Also, do while loops are really ugly, and you can do it much smoother with just two for loops:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] number = new int[5];
    double sum = 0;
    int num=0,i;
    for(i=0;i<5&&num!=-99;i++){
        num = scan.nextInt();
        number[i] = num;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
        System.out.println(number[k]);
        sum+=number[k];
    }
    System.out.println(sum/(i+1));      
}
```